# UICollectionView. How to insert new items behind the scene?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have a collectionView with one row. In performance purposes on start I load only part of items and scroll (let it be) to the 6th item of 30. Then I insert rest of items (it can be hundred) in the beginning and collection view switches to new 6 element not stays on the old. I've tried to use scrollToItemAtIndexPath on insertion completion, but it shows new item first and then switching to the old.

How to insert new items behind the scene? I mean to force collectionView behave in the way if no updates where made and all items always were?

```
- (void)addDateStorage
{
NSDate* currentPastDate = [dateStorage objectAtIndex:0];

NSMutableArray* indexPathes = [NSMutableArray array];

for(int i=0; i<DAYS_IN_YEAR; i++)
{
    [dateStorage insertObject:currentPastDate atIndex:0];

    currentPastDate = [currentPastDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:SECONDS_IN_DAY*(-1)];

    [indexPathes addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];


}

    [self.calendar insertItemsAtIndexPaths:indexPathes];

}
```

I've tried to use performBatchUpdates: and reloadData, but I have same result.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to modify your model (load more elements).

Second, tell your collectionView to reload data (it should see updated number of elements and still show only currently visible elements) and no scrolling will be needed.